# OpenCV track objects from a stream in an external window on screen

Tags: opencv, real-time, tracking, video-processing

I want to track fast objects from a live-stream on my display.

Is it possible? Any advice for me?

Thank you very much!!

Enrico

*edit:

For example: On my screen runs a single window with a live-stream, and I want to analyze it with some measurement **in real time**, e.g. velocity of an object.

I could not find any information about analyzing a window from/on a screen, only from a camera.

Comment: Please be more descriptive.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it is now more understandable.. sorry for the less description.

Comment: Start by reading about `cvCaptureFromCAM()`, `cv::threshold` and `findContours`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but it does not answer my question. I want to track a video or stream, which runs live on my desktop in a window. CaptureFromCam() does not analyze my desktop/window. best regards..